# XSLT Transformation result different in Windows and Unix

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an interesting and Wierd problem. When I run the XSLT transformation programmatically using Eclipse IDE, I get the desired output as follows:

```
      <Schedule>
      <Date>10/13/2013</Date>
      <Amount>2000</Amount>
      </Schedule>
```

Whereas using the same XSLT in my Solaris box, the transformation result is:

```
       <Schedule>
       <Amount>2000.0</Amount>
       </Schedule>
```

The mystery being that now the

```
      <Date>10/13/2013</Date>
```

block is not visible in UNIX. Also the amount is now 2000.0 compared to 2000 I get in my Eclipse output.
I am pretty sure that the SAME XSLT is being picked up in both the OS. I am really perplexed as to why the transformation outputs will be deifferent in Windows ( desired) vs Solaris ( undesirable). Looking forward to unlocking the mystery from all the Gurus out there.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].  Unless you edit your post and include the XSLT and the input, and tell us which specific transformation engines you used, this question will likely get closed.

Comment: You're "pretty sure" it's the same XSLT?  I'd start by checking that.  I'm pretty sure it's not.

Comment: Hi Harpo, I am sure I used the same XSLT because I looked into the logs. I am using Xalan 2.7.1 for processing. How do I check which transformation Engine is being picked up. I apologize if I could not answer all your questions because I am new to XSLT.

Comment: Hi Jim, I have added the input XML and the XSLT being used

Comment: @VinodMadan Are you sure this actually runs? Just copy and pasting what you have provided won't actually run. The first error I got was a missing closing tag. After that was an error about a few variables that you define multiple times in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I finally figured out the reason. In Unix, the xslt was being validated against a XSD which required the Date field to be DateType, i.e YYYY-MM-DD whereas I was passing the date in MM/DD/YYYY. Ironically, when I ran it in eclipse IDE, it took the MM/DD/YYYY value without complaining. Anyways, For now, my problems are solved and thanks everyone for looking into it.